# Using linq to filter observablecollection by textbox prevents english typing

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, windows-runtime

First of all, while there are many answered questions about using linq to filter an observablecollection via a user-inputted textbox, but nothing about when running the code, it prevents me from typing in English.

To explain my code, I have a simple class Person with 2 string properties KName and EName which will represent a Korean name and an English Name. Holding these Persons will be an ObservableCollection named persons.

```
    class Person
    {
        public string KName { get; set; }
        public string EName { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
    ObservableCollection<Person> persons;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        Person s = new Person();
        s.KName = "홍길동";
        s.EName = "Hong Kil-dong";
        persons.Add(s);

        Person t = new Person();
        t.KName = "김지영";
        t.EName = "Kim Ji-young";
        persons.Add(t);

        Person u = new Person();
        u.KName = "최철수";
        u.EName = "Choi Chul-soo";
        persons.Add(u);

        this.DataContext = persons;
    }
```

On the xaml side, I have a textbox with a KeyDown event handler that'll check if the Enter Key is pressed to process the search and a ListView which will display the results of the filter.

```
<Page
    x:Class="TextboxTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TextboxTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" Height="70" Margin="15"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"  KeyDown="SearchTextBox_Enter"/>
        <ListView x:Name="SearchResults" Margin="15" Height="500">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock Width="200" Text="{Binding Path=KName}"
                                   TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Width="200" Text="{Binding Path= EName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and the KeyDown handler

```
    private void SearchTextBox_Enter(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            string txt = SearchTextBox.Text;
            if(SearchResults.SelectedItem != null)
                SearchResults.SelectedItem = null;

            var filter = from Person in persons
                            let kname = Person.KName
                            let ename = Person.EName
                            where ename.Contains(txt) ||
                            kname.Contains(txt)
                            orderby kname
                            select Person;


            SearchResults.ItemsSource = filter;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

So my problem is that I can type in Korean, but I cannot type in English in the textbox. I can copy English text from somewhere else, paste it into the textbox, and it'll filter as expected. Removing the KeyDown handler from the textbox, it'll type in English fine. So the problem must be the KeyDown handler. Does anyone see anything wrong with my code? Or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix SearchBoxTextBox_Enter method.

```
e.Handled = true;
```

must be placed inside of IF-expression, like:

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
{
    // filtering...
    e.Handled = true;
}
```